# Electroweak Precision Observables

Tags: terminology, beyond-the-standard-model, electroweak

I was reading some papers on electroweak theory. There I found the term "electroweak precision observables".

My questions are the following:

1. What are the electroweak precision observables?
2. How are they related to beyond the standard model physics?

Comment: See Don Lincoln's video [Accelerator Science: Proton vs. Electron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GpfomQ3muU)

Comment: Have you seen section 31.1 of Schwartz, *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model*?

Comment: see this talk https://indico.cern.ch/event/550509/contributions/2432675/attachments/1396333/2129167/sven-status.pdf

Comment: Actually the talk from Ayres Freitas made it more clear. Thanks for the suggestions.